# How to display data from SQL Server on a DataGridView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I want to load or show the data from SQL Server on a `DataGridView`.

The build succeeds and there's no error when I run it. There's nothing wrong in form `modul_koneksi` (I think) because it works on my other form (`form_login`)

However, nothing shows up in my `DataGridView`. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FormProduk
    Private Sub FormProduk_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim str As String = "Data Source=Fahriy;Initial Catalog=DBLogin;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(str)
        Dim com As String = "Select * From tbl_user"
        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(com, connection)
        Dim dataset As New DataSet()
        dataadapter.Fill(dataset, "tbl_user")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Since you are new consider reading the [tour] to get an understand on how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

You should define which table to load in the `DataGridView`:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables("tbl_user")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info to tell, are you sure your connection string `str` is correct. You can try change to this code:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim str As String = "Data Source=Fahriy;Initial Catalog=DBLogin;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(str)
    Dim cmd As String = "Select * From tbl_user"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn)
    Dim tabeluser As New DataSet
    adapter.Fill(tabeluser)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = tabeluser.Tables
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the `.DataSource` property with `dataset.Tables`. Instead you need to set it with a `DataTable` located in your `DataSet`:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables("tbl_user")
```

However I think you could simplify the code a little by getting rid of the `SqlDataAdapter` and loading straight into a `DataTable`

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader())

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

I would also consider implementing [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement):

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

With the changes your code would look something like this:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Fahriy;Initial Catalog=DBLogin;Integrated Security=True"),
      cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  tbl_user", con)
    con.Open()

    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
End Using

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```